# Why do asparagine and glutamine have two different abbreviations?

Tags: proteins, amino-acids

I'm looking at amino acid abbreviations and on every site I visit, asparagine and glutamine have two different abbreviations. Is there a reason for this? Do they represent different forms of the amino acid that may have different properties?

I'm looking at the abbreviations on this site as an example: 
http://www.hgmd.cf.ac.uk/docs/cd_amino.html

On the page, asparagine has an abbreviation of 'N' and an abbreviation of 'B'. The abbreviation 'B' doesn't correspond to a codon so why is it there?

Glutamine also has two abbreviations ('Q' and 'Z'). The abbreviation 'Z' doesn't correspond to a codon either.

Comment: Welcome to Bio. Are you askinh whether Arg and Gln are different amono acids??

Comment: Great edit - @Roland has given the right answer - see the official [IUPAC website](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Class/MLACourse/Modules/MolBioReview/iupac_aa_abbreviations.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The abbreviation Asx (B) is used if it is uncertain whether the amino acid at a given position in a peptide sequence is Asparagine or Aspartate. Similarly, Glx (Z) is used when there is uncertainty between Glutamine / Glutamate.

These two pairs of amino acids can be ambiguous in peptide sequences because Asp/Asn and Glu/Gln differs only by a terminal amide (-NH2) group in the side chain, and this amide group can be spontaneously lost from proteins by a [deamidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deamidation) reaction. When this occurs, asparagine is converted to aspartate/isoaspartate, and glutamine to glutamate/glutamate. These cannot be distinguished from "real" aspartate or glutamate by [classic peptide sequencing](http://actachemscand.org/pdf/acta_vol_04_p0283-0293.pdf), nor by mass spectrometry, since their mass is identical. Hence, protein sequences obtained directly from protein frequently contains Asx/Glx entries.

Answer (score 4):

Asparagine (Asn) and glutamine (Gln) are derived forms of the amino acids aspartic acid (Asp) and glutamic acid (Glu). 
Both amino acid pairs (Asn/Asp, Gln/Glu) consist of the same carbon backbone, 
their side chains only differ in their functional group.
Aspartic and glutamic acid include a carboxylic acid (-COOH), whereas asparagine and glutamine are carboxamides (-CO-NH2).

Here you can see asparagine and aspartic acid as example:

[image: Asparagine (Asn)]
Asparagine (Asn)

[image: Aspartic acid (Asp)]
Aspartic acid (Asp)

Answer (score 1):

The reason is simple: These are two different amino acids with different side chains. They look very similar, but they are not:

[image]

This is [L-Glutamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutamine), its chemical formula is C<sub>5</sub>H<sub>10</sub>N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>.

[image]

This is [L-Asparagine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asparagine), its chemical formula is: C<sub>4</sub>H<sub>5</sub>N<sub>2</sub>O<sub>3</sub>. This shows that L-Asparagine has one CH<sub>2</sub> less than L-Glutamine.

Answer (score 0):

From the reference in the question, the query seems to be asking "Why does an amino acid have two abbreviations, such as Asn and N for asparagine, and Gln and Q for glutamine?"

This is because both abbreviations are commonly used in the scientific literature.  The longer, 3-letter, abbreviation is useful because it is a recognizable shortening of the amino acid's name.  The 1-letter abbreviation tends to be very arbitrary (e.g. Q for glutamine), so it is not very mnemonic. However, the single letter form is much easier to make use of for long sequences of amino acids, as in giving the sequence of a particular protein.